# ODBC Connection for SQL Server 2012 & 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create ODBC connection for SQL Server 2012 and 2016, but not sure which version of drivers i have to install. Can you please help me with this?

Thanks,
Sujith

Comment: That depends on what features you want, or aren't "bothered" about: [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15). Though, unless your operating doesn't support it, I see little reason to not use the latest version.

Comment: You can find the compatibility matrix [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15).